WPF converter resource makes unrelated UI content disappear
I've been a WPF developer for about 10 years now, and I've seen a lot of idiocy from it in all shapes and sizes, but today I just stumbled upon a fresh batch of male cow manure that just absolutely takes the cake. Every cake in existence, actually.
Putting a converter at the top of a Window's resources list somehow breaks resources of UI objects that come after it.
Here is the simplest example of an application that reproduces this issue, with the least amount of code I can muster:
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Converters"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <converters:BaseConverter x:Key="test"/>

        <Grid x:Key="TestItemTemplateGrid" x:Shared="false">
            <Button Content="{Binding StringFormat='Button {0}'}" Width="300"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ItemsControl>
        <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
        <system:Int32>1</system:Int32>
        <system:Int32>2</system:Int32>
        <system:Int32>3</system:Int32>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource TestItemTemplateGrid}" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>

The converter:
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace WpfApp1.Converters
{
    public class BaseConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        public virtual object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
}

This is just a simple attempt to load a variable amount of items inside an ItemsControl, where each item is a ContentControl that populates itself to be a Grid defined in a resource.
This is what the app is supposed to look like based on this xaml:

But here is what it actually looks like:

It's like the x:Shared is breaking and becoming true or something, just because a converter resource came before it.
Things I've tested:

The converter's key name doesn't matter
The converter's type and/or method implementations don't matter
The ItemsControl having a bound ItemsSource vs hard-coded entries doesn't matter
The actual content inside the Grid doesn't matter

Of course, removing the <converters:BaseConverter x:Key="test"/> fixes it, but here's the real kicker: Putting it last in the resources list instead ALSO fixes it.
...Wow. Just, wow. What is this? Am I dead? Am I dreaming? Is April fools day programmed into WPF, but it's bugged (like everything else) and came a month late? Can someone explain this? I'm losing my mind here.
The project file, in case it matters:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>


Out of curiosity, why you make the converter inherit MarkupExtension?

Just so I can pass it into bindings directly instead of making it a resource... which is what I'd normally be doing, but today I actually did have a situation where I needed the same converter multiple times, so I did the resource thing. And then it broke everything, hence now we're here!

I see. I just found your BaseConverter doesn't need to be a converter to reproduce the issue. Only inheriting MarkupExtension seems to suffice. If so, this is a matter of MarkupExtension rather than IValueConverter.

BTW It should be known that the order matters. You can have a style based on another style, but it has to be defined before. So you should not be so surprised by that.

The error occurs if MarkupExtension comes first in the resources.
If you separate IValueConverter and MarkupExtension, then when creating the IValueConverter first and then MarkupExtension, there is no error:
namespace WpfApp1.Converters
{
    public class BaseConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public virtual object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

    }

    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(BaseConverter))]
    public class BaseConverterExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return new BaseConverter();
        }
    }
}

    <Window.Resources>
        <converters:BaseConverter x:Key="test"/>
        <converters:BaseConverterExtension x:Key="test1"/>

        <Grid x:Key="TestItemTemplateGrid" x:Shared="false">
            <Button Content="{Binding StringFormat='Button {0}'}" Width="300"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window.Resources>

If you create it in the reverse order, the error appears:
    <Window.Resources>
        <converters:BaseConverterExtension x:Key="test1"/>
        <converters:BaseConverter x:Key="test"/>

        <Grid x:Key="TestItemTemplateGrid" x:Shared="false">
            <Button Content="{Binding StringFormat='Button {0}'}" Width="300"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window.Resources>

This error is not caused by your implementation. This also happens with default implementations of the markup extension:
    <Window.Resources>
        <!--<converters:BaseConverterExtension x:Key="test1"/>-->
        <RelativeSource Mode="Self" x:Key="test1"/>
        <converters:BaseConverter x:Key="test"/>

        <Grid x:Key="TestItemTemplateGrid" x:Shared="false">
            <Button Content="{Binding StringFormat='Button {0}'}" Width="300"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window.Resources>


Iiiinteresting.  Thank you for your service Mr. Hasp! So what's the conclusion then? That this is just the biggest bug in wpf?

@Pojo I can't say what the reason is. ResourceDictionary is a specific collection and has its own limitations. For example, you cannot create a Binding instance in it. There are probably other restrictions.
